# Accessing html attributes with Floki

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to get the image from the HTML body I have scraped with [Floki](https://hexdocs.pm/floki/Floki.html#attribute/2). Right now the body is

```
[
  {"div", [{"class", "a-cover-image"}, {"data-state", "not-initialised"}],
   [
     {"div",
      [
        {"class", "content"},
        {"data-image",
         "/sites/default/files/legacy/khloe-kardashian-anxiety-pregnancy.png"},
        {"data-text", "A photo of Khloe Kardashian dressed up for a night out"}
      ],
      [
        {"div",
         [
           {"class", "a-cover-image__cover a-cover-image__cover-loading-inner"},
           {"style",
            "background-image: url('/sites/default/files/legacy/khloe-kardashian-anxiety-pregnancy.png')"}
         ], []}
      ]},
     {"div",
      [
        {"class", "a-cover-image__cover a-cover-image__cover-small"},
        {"data-image",
         "/sites/default/files/styles/1x1/public/legacy/khloe-kardashian-anxiety-pregnancy.png?itok=agZilCJ6"},
        {"data-text", "A photo of Khloe Kardashian dressed up for a night out"},
        {"data-height", ""},
        {"data-width", ""}
      ], []},
     {"div",
      [
        {"class", "a-cover-image__cover a-cover-image__cover-medium"},
        {"data-image",
         "/sites/default/files/styles/3x2/public/legacy/khloe-kardashian-anxiety-pregnancy.png?itok=tnPqQNhC"},
        {"data-text", "A photo of Khloe Kardashian dressed up for a night out"},
        {"data-height", ""},
        {"data-width", ""}
      ], []},
     {"div",
      [
        {"class", "a-cover-image__cover a-cover-image__cover-large"},
        {"data-image",
         "/sites/default/files/styles/16x9/public/legacy/khloe-kardashian-anxiety-pregnancy.png?itok=YgdCfuT2"},
        {"data-text", "A photo of Khloe Kardashian dressed up for a night out"},
        {"data-height", ""},
        {"data-width", ""}
      ], []},
     {"div",
      [
        {"class", "a-cover-image__cover a-cover-image__cover-xl"},
        {"data-image",
         "/sites/default/files/styles/16x9/public/legacy/khloe-kardashian-anxiety-pregnancy.png?itok=YgdCfuT2"},
        {"data-text", "A photo of Khloe Kardashian dressed up for a night out"},
        {"data-height", ""},
        {"data-width", ""}
      ], []}
   ]}
]
```

So I'm trying to get `data-image` from `a-cover-image__cover-small` and I know I can get that element from the body like so

`body |> Floki.find(".a-cover-image__cover-small")` and the output will be

```
[
  {"div",
   [
     {"class", "a-cover-image__cover a-cover-image__cover-small"},
     {"data-image",
      "/sites/default/files/styles/1x1/public/legacy/khloe-kardashian-anxiety-pregnancy.png?itok=agZilCJ6"},
     {"data-text", "A photo of Khloe Kardashian dressed up for a night out"},
     {"data-height", ""},
     {"data-width", ""}
   ], []}
]
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how to get `data-text`, how can I return it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `Floki.attribute/2`:

```
body |> Floki.find(".a-cover-image__cover-small") |> Floki.attribute("data-text")
# => ["A photo of Khloe Kardashian dressed up for a night out"]
```

If you know that there will be only one matching element, you can extract it with a pattern match:

```
[text] = body |> Floki.find(".a-cover-image__cover-small") |> Floki.attribute("data-text")
text # => "A photo of Khloe Kardashian dressed up for a night out"
```

Comment: omg, if I start to explain that for some reasons I couldn't do that, it will be funny, but thanks for the matching element example